# What does this notation mean? (Satisfiability / set notation)

Tags: notation, satisfiability

I am studying a satisfiablity course as a part of my computer science degree. My lecturer introduced some notation without explaining it and I can't seem to find out through Google.

Let F be a clause set i.e. a set of clauses "ANDEDed" together, where a clause is a set of variables "ORed" together.

Here's my problem:

F' = F \ {D}

What does the "F \ {D}" mean?

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $A\backslash B$ is the set of elements in $A$ that are not in $B$.

Comment: What is $D$ (and $\{D\}$) supposed to be? Without that context, we will only be guessing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In standard set parlance, it means all elements of $F$, except (possibly) for $D$.  He may mean all elements of $F$ anded, excluding $D$ if $D\in F$.